# boxplot in R, aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same length as data

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm doing some analysis on the auto miles per gallon data from UCI website:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Auto+MPG

I factored the first column into either high or low mileage:

```
mpg01 = I(auto1$mpg >= median(auto1$mpg))
Auto = data.frame(mpg01, auto1[,-1])
head(Auto)

    mpg01 cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration year origin
 1 FALSE         8          307        130   3504         12.0   70      1
 2 FALSE         8          350        165   3693         11.5   70      1
 3 FALSE         8          318        150   3436         11.0   70      1
 4 FALSE         8          304        150   3433         12.0   70      1
 5 FALSE         8          302        140   3449         10.5   70      1
 6 FALSE         8          429        198   4341         10.0   70      1
```

Now I want to make boxplot for each of the columns from dataframe, factored by the first column.

```
vars <- c("cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin")
ggplot(Auto) + geom_bar(aes(y=vars, fill=factor(mpg01)))
```

And I get the error "Aes must be either length 1 or the same as data"

The dimension of "Auto" dataframe is 392x8

I can just use boxplot for each column, but want to know if there's a way to combine them into one. Thanks!

Comment: Can you `dput` auto1 dataset, or subset of it. I can't tell from the link which data you are using.

Comment: Okay, just added some data for the 8 columns.

Comment: @ajax2000 In your code you use `geom_bar` but you want to create boxplots.... is that correct?

Comment: I have solution for you, but please use `dput(Auto)` and paste the output, this allows your data to be easily copied.  The problem here is you cannot assign the colnames to `vars` and call it as `aes(y=vars)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated to explain the error generated:** The error is generated because `aes(x, y...)` need to be defined to describe how the data frame variables should be mapped into the geoms.  In your case, no `x` variable has been defined for `geom_boxplot`.  In order to define the `x` variable to be each of the columns of your df, the df needs to be reshaped to long format (e.g. using `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather`)

Below is the solution that should work which is based on mtcars and not your data. If not, we can troubleshoot it once once you `dput(Auto)` for me.  The plot you generate should look like the one I attached. First, reshape your data.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars_melt <- melt(mtcars)
```

I can now define `x` in `aes`.  Note: Notice the difference between the 2 cases below when used with `facet_wrap`.

```
# First with no facet_wrap
ggplot(mtcars_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot()
# Case 1 with facet_wrap
ggplot(mtcars_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable)
# Case 2 with facet_wrap
ggplot(mtcars_melt, aes(x="", y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

In case 1, I define `x=variable` in `aes`, but with `facet_wrap` it forces each facet to have all x variables present, however if I set `x=""`, it allows for each facet to hold only 1 x variable.

Now to allow the y-axis to have independent scales, I can set `scales="free_y"`

```
ggplot(mtcars_melt, aes(x="", y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_y")
```

Alternatively, I can set `scales="free"` to apply to both x and y axis and use it with `x=variable` to arrive at a similar solution.

```
ggplot(mtcars_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free")
```

[image]

**Edited:** The code below should work for your particular data set:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
vars <- c("cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin")
Auto_melt <- melt(Auto[, vars])
ggplot(Auto_melt, aes(x="", y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_y")
```

**Edited with code to separate by mpg as requested:**
Redefine vars by including "mpg01", and melt the data by mpg id. Use mpg01 as aes x value.

```
Auto <- structure(list(mpg01 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), cylinders = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), displacement = c(307, 350, 318, 304, 302), horsepower = c(130L, 165L, 150L, 150L, 140L), weight = c(3504L, 3693L, 3436L, 3433L, 3449L), acceleration = c(12, 11.5, 11, 12, 10.5), year = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L), origin = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("mpg01", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame") 

vars <- c("mpg01", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin")
Auto_melt <- melt(Auto[, vars], id.vars="mpg01")
ggplot(Auto_melt, aes(x=mpg01, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_boxplot() +    facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks R.S., this is almost exactly what I'm looking for. I wanted to also divide each boxplot based on the first column "mpg01", since I turned it into values of 0 and 1. 1 being above the median and 0 being below. So under each variable, there will be 2 boxplots. x-axis will be "mpg01" and y-axis will be the value of the variable. is this possible?

Comment: @ajax2000 please dput(Auto) as I have requested and update your question with the output.  This puts your data in a form I can easily copy and paste on my terminal, instead of having to format your data myself as it is in display form.  I prefer to check the code on your actual data.

Comment: this is the first 5 rows: structure(list(mpg01 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), cylinders = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
    displacement = c(307, 350, 318, 304, 302), horsepower = c(130L, 
    165L, 150L, 150L, 140L), weight = c(3504L, 3693L, 3436L, 
    3433L, 3449L), acceleration = c(12, 11.5, 11, 12, 10.5), 
    year = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L), origin = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L)), .Names = c("mpg01", "cylinders", "displacement", 
"horsepower", "weight", "acceleration", "year", "origin"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Ah, by divide you mean separate the mpg categories in the plot, not divide the values by mpg which I now realize are 1's or 0's. I edited the answer above, for this case I redefined vars by including "mpg01", and melted the data by mpg id, then used mpg01 as my x value.

Comment: Okay thanks, I see you did now. For the melt function, i just included all Auto data and it worked. I think I will need more practice on ggplot. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great, it should also work for categorical variables although you will not get a boxplot but a simple line. Consider accepting the answer if this is complete so this can be marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you should tidy your data, then to draw boxplot.
I download the data from the website :

```
> head(df)
  mpg01 cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration year origin
1    18         8          307        130   3504         12.0   70      1
2    15         8          350        165   3693         11.5   70      1
3    18         8          318        150   3436         11.0   70      1
4    16         8          304        150   3433         12.0   70      1
5    17         8          302        140   3449         10.5   70      1
6    15         8          429        198   4341         10.0   70      1
```

Use **gather{tidyr}** to tidy data.

```
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
tidy_df <- df %>% gather("vars","values",-mpg01)
```

And tidy_df is:

```
> head(tidy_df)
  mpg01      vars values
1    18 cylinders      8
2    15 cylinders      8
3    18 cylinders      8
4    16 cylinders      8
5    17 cylinders      8
6    15 cylinders      8
```

Then you can draw boxplot

```
ggplot(data=tidy_df,aes(vars,values)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=vars))
```

It looks like that:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vida. I made the first column "mpg01" into 0s and 1s. 1 being greater than median and 0 being below. is it possible to take that in to the boxplots? Each variable will have 2 boxplots.

Comment: @ajax2000 I think can do it, try `aes(fill = vars, colour = mpg01)`

Comment: Thanks for your help